# The complement of $F_\sigma$ is $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, lebesgue-measure

Would it be true or false that the complement $F_\sigma$ set is a $G_\delta$ set?

I've tried that $F_\sigma$ is a countable union of closed sets, but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

You may first try proving
$$
\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right)^c = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c.
$$

Comment: Ah, by doing the above I see that I get that A^c would then be a countable intersection of open sets. Would this make the statement above True?

Comment: @M.Joshnson Yes, it would! Also, you can obtain that the complement of a $G_\delta$ set is $F_\sigma$ by using a similar relation.